# Stretched image in canvas when background is set in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

Ok so i was finally able to get user's signature over an image .
And through all i was able to learn from canvas and saving an image + user drawings , i knew that i had to set the canvas background like so :

```
mDrawLayout.setBackground(d);
```

But my issue is : image gets really really stretched from the original one , here s the original image :

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yWJ8.jpg)

heres the out put on the canvas by setting its background :
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd2iq.jpg)

heres my mDrawLayout class :

```
public class DrawingView extends View {
public int width;
public  int height;
static Path drawPath;
private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
static int paintColor = 0xFFFF0000;
private  float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
private Canvas drawCanvas;
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
private boolean erase=false;


public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    setupDrawing();
    setErase(erase);
}
private void setupDrawing(){
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}
public void clearDrawing()
{

    setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);


    onSizeChanged(width, height, width, height);
    invalidate();

    setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
}
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    width = w;
    height = h;
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

public void setErase(boolean isErase){
    erase=isErase;
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    if(erase) {
        setupDrawing();
        int srcColor= 0x00000000;

        PorterDuff.Mode mode = PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR;
        PorterDuffColorFilter porterDuffColorFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(srcColor, mode);

        drawPaint.setColorFilter(porterDuffColorFilter);

        drawPaint.setColor(srcColor);
        drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(mode));

    }
    else {

        setupDrawing();

    }
}

//************************************   draw view  *************************************************************

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}

//***************************   respond to touch interaction   **************************************************

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    canvasPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();
    //respond to down, move and up events

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    //redraw
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

//***********************************   return current alpha   ***********************************************
public int getPaintAlpha(){
    return Math.round((float)STROKE_WIDTH/255*100);
}

//**************************************  set alpha   ******************************************************
public void setPaintAlpha(int newAlpha){
    STROKE_WIDTH=Math.round((float)newAlpha/100*255);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(newAlpha);
}
```

heres my canvas class :

```
public class SignatureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SeekBar mThickness;
private AnexoTemporario imagePath;
private DrawingView mDrawLayout;
Button erase, draw;
private Paint drawPaint = new Paint();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signature);
    mThickness = findViewById(R.id.thickness);
    mDrawLayout = findViewById(R.id.viewDraw);
    erase = findViewById(R.id.erase);
    draw= findViewById(R.id.draw);
    imagePath = (AnexoTemporario) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("IMAGEURL");
    File file = new File(imagePath.getFilePath());
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    mDrawLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mDrawLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mDrawLayout.setEnabled(true);


    mDrawLayout.setBackground(d);
    mDrawLayout.setRotation(90);




    mThickness.setMax(50);
    mThickness.setProgress(10);
    mDrawLayout.setPaintAlpha(mThickness.getProgress());
    int currLevel = mDrawLayout.getPaintAlpha();
    mThickness.setProgress(currLevel);
    mDrawLayout.invalidate();
    erase.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        saveDrawing();
        drawPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mDrawLayout.setErase(true);

    });

    draw.setOnClickListener(v -> mDrawLayout.clearDrawing());

    mThickness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser) {
            mDrawLayout.setPaintAlpha(mThickness.getProgress());
        }
    });
}
public void saveDrawing()
{
    Bitmap whatTheUserDrewBitmap = mDrawLayout.getDrawingCache();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    whatTheUserDrewBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);

    GetImageTask task = new GetImageTask(whatTheUserDrewBitmap, base64string -> {

        try {
            WriteSDCard writeSDCard = new WriteSDCard(this);
            writeSDCard.writeToSDFile("assinatura.png", base64string.getBytes());

            Toast.makeText(this, "Assinatura Salva!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("ASSINATURA", "assinatura.png");
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Erro ao tentar salvar assinatura!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

}
```

xml file :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".canvas.SignatureActivity" >

<mobi.stos.gwmobile.canvas.DrawingView
    android:id="@+id/viewDraw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ll"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/erase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thickness"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="SALVAR"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/draw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/erase"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="APAGAR"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Tamanho da linha" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/thickness"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewDraw"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewDraw" />
</LinearLayout>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`View.setBackground(drawable)` seems like it just applies that `Drawable` and scales it to fit the `View`. So if that `View` is a different aspect ratio than the bitmap, it gets stretched.

The simplest approach would be something like this - stick your background in an `ImageView` behind your `DrawingView`, and constrain it to the same size as the `DrawingView`. Make the scaling `CENTER_INSIDE` (to make sure the whole image fits into the `ImageView`, while maintaining the aspect ratio) or `FIT_CENTER` (same, but it'll also scale *up* so the image touches the sides):

```
<!-- specify this one first, so viewDraw is on top of it -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/drawingBackground"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/viewDraw"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/viewDraw"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/viewDraw"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/viewDraw" />

<mobi.stos.gwmobile.canvas.DrawingView
    android:id="@+id/viewDraw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ll"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

And then you can use `setImageBitmap` on that `ImageView` to display a pic.

---

The other approach would be passing and storing the background bitmap in `DrawingView`, and drawing that to the `Canvas` as part of the `onDraw` call, using `drawBitmap`. That's more involved, because you'd have to create a `Rect` with the appropriate width and height (depending on the view's `width` and `height`) to maintain the aspect ratio, and then work out the *x* and *y* coordinates to draw it so it's centred. And you'd need to recalculate that every time a new background bitmap is provided, or whenever the `onSizeChanged` is called on the `View`.

---

But passing the background bitmap into your custom view also gives you the ability to *define the size of the `DrawingView` itself* by overriding `onMeasure`, and basically constraining the View to fit the `Bitmap`'s aspect ratio. The problem with the other approaches is that the `DrawingView` is whatever size it is, and the background is just drawn into that space filling up whatever it happens to fill.

So that means you can draw over the empty parts of the background - and that might not be a problem! But if it *is*, you could override `onMeasure` to make use of the potential width and height your View *could be*, and limit one of those axes to constrain the whole View to fit your Bitmap.

That's a little involved and I don't have time to write an example, but [here's an article on `onMeasure`](https://medium.com/@quiro91/custom-view-mastering-onmeasure-a0a0bb11784d) that shows you how you can control the *actual* size of your View, if that's a thing you want to pursue.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a covered answer. 
Ive tried the first approach you mentioned, it did work perfeclt i drew on top of an image that fit to the screen perfectly, but when i tried SAVING the canvas it gave me a black screen .
to fix it , i set the canvas background AS the user presses SAVE, so that i could have a signed image in the end, it *stretches* as he presses save back again but it works fine , i'll mark this answer as final but if u could provide further help regarding this : ( a way i could s ave the bitmap s image as i get the canvas drawing cache i would appreciate.

Comment: @VictorPierre Oh right, I just assumed you were saving "what the user drew" and not the background as well! If you were drawing the background *as part of your custom view* that would be simple enough, you'd just create a new `Bitmap` and a `Canvas` wrapping it, and draw to that exactly the same as you do in `onDraw`. If you're doing the `ImageView` approach, could you get `Bitmap`s from *both* of them? And then create a `Canvas` for the background one, and `drawBitmap` the other one onto it, and save the result?. Basically what you're doing now, but pulling from both views and combining them

Comment: Just bear in mind the `drawingCache` stuff is deprecated, and has basically been unnecessary since API 11 (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getDrawingCache()) so trying to access it (say on the `ImageView`) might cause issues if it's not *using* a cache. You could try calling `buildDrawingCache()` on it first (probably not guaranteed to work everywhere though) or maybe try `backgroundImageView.getDrawable().draw(outputBitmapCanvas)` - but I've never done this so I'm just thinking what's worth trying out!

Comment: i did achieve what i was aiming for with your help with the imageView and by using a method to combine two bitmaps together from the drawingCache and the ImageView , heres the  method : ( mines got a few custom twerks ) 
    private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }

Comment: @VictorPierre nice, looks good! Overlaying your custom view over an `ImageView` is kind of a quick hack (not that that's bad!) compared to making it part of your custom view's logic, so I'm glad you got it to work for what you're doing!